# Gmail mailbox full

Tags: gmail, g-suite

My issue is a client's Gmail mailbox is full. They run Gmail G-Suite for Business. I cannot track down the messages using the space.

If I do the search "in:all" the result is 1-50 of 15,083. When I do the search "in:all before:2018/6/18" I get 1-50 of 88 and I do the search "in:all after:2018/6/18" I get 1-50 of 186. So where did the other 14,809 message go? More importantly how do I track down the messages using 30gb of storage space.

The storage information says its all Gmail and no Photos or Drive space contributes to the storage use. Also there is nothing in "Trash"

Maybe there is a better place to look than label:all?

Comment: Here's a relevant support thread from Gmail. https://support.google.com/mail/thread/4151253?hl=en Are you sure that the client's Trash folder is empty?
Are you sure that the client doesn't have 2 accounts open in Gmail (e.g, a Business account and a personal account. Maybe it's the personal account that is over limit)

Comment: There is nothing in Trash and although I found some lables containting the word trash ie Trash\Folder1, they were all empty. I thought I would add that the client uses POP3 to fetch these mails into Outlook just incase thats a relevant fact.

Comment: Ah! An important clarification!  If you configure POP in Gmail, you have the option of choosing to retain (in Inbox) or archive the messages in Gmail as well as delivering them to the client.  You said you looked under tag All, I am not sure that includes Archived.  Just to be sure, check under 'All Mail' in Gmail website.